# Loading file from Buff

Tags: c

the printf returns the right buff however open returns an error iirc

```
int readicon(const char * titleid, const char * value)
{

    ini_file init;


    load_ini(&init, "INI_FILE_PATH_HERE");


    char buffer[500];
    char buff[500];

    ini_get_string(&init, titleid, value, "NULL", buff, 500);
    sprintf(buffer, "%s", buff);
    printf(buff); // returns the right path from the ini
    loadpng(buff);

}
```

Open returns "Invalid arg." but the buff returns "FILE_PATH" so idk the problem
please not this loadpng is know to work fine with a hardcoded path (not from buff)

Comment: Where is `open` or `Open` anywhere in this code?

Comment: Is it a problem in the "ini" functions, or a problem in the `loadpng` function (neither of which you show us)? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and also please tell us the contents of `buff`. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: the ini functions work, everything works by themselves the loadpng returns the open error

Comment: also the buff returns/shows "FILE_PATH_HERE"

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Is the path an absolute or a relative path? If it's relative, are you sure it's correct in relation to the process working directory? Are you sure that the contents of the string is what you expect it to be? Have you used a debugger to see it? There's no newline or otherwise unprintable character in the string?

Comment: What ***is*** "FILE_PATH_HERE"? What does it ***mean***? We don't have the same code you have, how could we? That [mcve] would be really useful now.

Comment: Yes, its a absolute path that works fine on its own (not from a buff) and no i dont *think* there is any unprintable characters in t

Comment: The `loadpng()` call uses `buff`, not `buffer`... That is very confusing since the result of `sprintf()` is just thrown away?

Answer (score 0):

i figured out you cant have quotes in paths in a buffer